# React Native's rnmapbox's offline implementation

Tags: react-native, mapbox

Good day,

I am trying to follow the offine-implementation example in rnmapbox's documentation in a bare React Native application. I zoom  in a part of the map, I hit "Create pack", disconnect from the internet, and hit "Get pack" to load the previously downloaded map. Instead of getting the pack back though, I get an error: Using MapView requires calling Mapbox.getInstance(Context context, String apiKey) before inflating or creating the view.

What to make of this, please?

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { StyleSheet, Button, Dimensions, TextInput } from "react-native";
    import Mapbox, { Camera, MapView, offlineManager } from "@rnmapbox/maps";
    import geoViewport from "@mapbox/geo-viewport";
    
    import Page from "../components/UI/Page";
    
    import { GlobalStyles } from "../constants/styles";
    const CENTER_COORD = [-73.970895, 40.723279];
    const MAPBOX_VECTOR_TILE_SIZE = 512;
    
    function Map(props) {

    const [packName, setPackName] = useState("pack-1");
    const [showEditTitle, setShowEditTitle] = useState(false);

return (

<Page {...props}>
  <Button
    title={`Pack name: ${packName}`}
    onPress={() => {
      setShowEditTitle(!showEditTitle);
    }}
  />
  {showEditTitle && (
    <TextInput
      value={packName}
      autoFocus={true}
      onChangeText={(text) => setPackName(text)}
      onBlur={() => setShowEditTitle(false)}
    />
  )}
  <Button
    title="Get all packs"
    onPress={async () => {
      const packs = await offlineManager.getPacks();
      console.log("=> packs:", packs);
      packs.forEach((pack) => {
        console.log(
          "pack:",
          pack,
          "name:",
          pack.name,
          "bounds:",
          pack?.bounds,
          "metadata",
          pack?.metadata
        );
      });
    }}
  />
  <Button
    title="Get pack"
    onPress={async () => {
      const pack = await offlineManager.getPack(packName);
      if (pack) {
        console.log(
          "pack:",
          pack,
          "name:",
          pack.name,
          "bounds:",
          pack?.bounds,
          "metadata",
          pack?.metadata
        );

        console.log("=> status", await pack?.status());
      }
    }}
  />
  <Button
    title="Resume pack"
    onPress={async () => {
      const pack = await offlineManager.getPack(packName);
      if (pack) {
        await pack.resume();
      }
    }}
  />
  <Button
    title="Create Pack"
    onPress={() => {
      const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
      const bounds = geoViewport.bounds(
        CENTER_COORD,
        12,
        [width, height],
        MAPBOX_VECTOR_TILE_SIZE
      );

      const options = {
        name: packName,
        styleURL: Mapbox.StyleURL.Street,
        bounds: [
          [bounds[0], bounds[1]],
          [bounds[2], bounds[3]],
        ],
        minZoom: 10,
        maxZoom: 20,
        metadata: {
          whatIsThat: "foo",
        },
      };
      offlineManager.createPack(options, (region, status) =>
        console.log(
          "=> progress callback region:",
          props,
          "status: ",
          status
        )
      );
    }}
  />
  <MapView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Camera zoomLevel={10} centerCoordinate={CENTER_COORD} />
  </MapView>
</Page>
  );
}
```

Comment: I managed to download my regions, but instead when I toggle network offline and move map I get 

Mapbox error MapLoad error Failed to load tile:  {"level": "error", "message": "MapLoad error Failed to load tile: "}